# With git how can i merge a repository that has already been merged?

Tags: git, merge, pull, git-merge, git-pull

I have a repository that i pulled the changes for, so now it is up to date with the remote repository. Except that now i realized that i needed to pull all of that repositories changes and keep none of mine. I want to go back in history so that i won't get an "Already up-to-date" when i pull. Also part two, how can i pull and get all of their changes keeping none of mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git reset --hard origin/otherbranchname
```

Assumes: You are on the branch you want to move, the remote is called origin, and you really want to blow away all of your commits.

`git reset` moves branch pointers around. This command simply plucks it from its current location and places it at the remotes' branch pointer, while changing all of the working copy files.